# PHP GD method imagecopy larger the image filesize than the origin image

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

In my work , I use PHP GD lib function imagecopy to add watermark to images , but find the generated image is larger than the origin image before , is there any way optimize filesize , except the jpegoptim to trim the exif metadata.

The test code on the github :  https://github.com/zeanwork/Watermark , u can test with exmaple , the to.jpg filesize is too much larger  than from.jpg and watermark.png filesize

[image]

file mediainfo

[image]

But I dont want image with watermark is to much larger than the origin file , In my test , the to.jpg filesize sometime 4 times of origin image

any best methods to reduce the filesize ?

Comment: What quality is the inagejpeg call (3rd arg)

Comment: I have add a image mediainfo

Answer (score 2):

It's the image quality, but again, I don't think it is possible to have identical JPEG image size, even if you just copy one jpg image to the other one. `Watermark` does save the image with 100 quality, which is the biggest. I guess your original image has no such big quality, thus the difference in the file size.

Just have a look at 204 line of the [Watermark class](https://github.com/zeanwork/Watermark/blob/master/watermark.php):

```
# Save image
$functionTarget($this->imgSource, $imgTarget, 100);
```

You'll have to hardcode it in order to change the quality.

Comment: yes , thanks , through the command to get the origin image quality : identify -format '%Q'